# Why does my loop end after the input is entered?

Tags: python, while-loop

The homework question is: "Write a program that reads an unspecified number of integers, determines how many positive and negative values have been read, and computes the total
and average of the input values (not counting zeros). Your program ends with the
input 0. Display the average as a floating-point number."

```
positive = 0
negative = 0
total = 0
count = 0

number = eval(input("Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0:"))
while number != 0:
    total += number
    count += 1
    if number > 0:
        positive += 1
    elif number < 0:
        negative += 1
    else:
        break

average = total/count
print("The number of positives is", positive)
print("The number of negatives is", negative)
print("The total is", total)
print("The average is", average)
```

After a number is inputted, the program does not output anything else.

Comment: Why are you using `eval()`? Please don't ever call that on untrusted user input.

Comment: Your program only prompts for input once because you don't prompt inside the loop.

Comment: Your loop loops until `number == 0`. Where do you change `number` in the loop?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by not prompting inside a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Write a program that reads an unspecified number of integers

That implies that you have to repeatedly take number inputs from the users, but using input() would only really input a single number at a time.

So you should input your number inside the while-loop, example:

```
while True:
    number = int(input("Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0:"))
    total += number
    count += 1
    if number > 0:
        positive += 1
    elif number < 0:
        negative += 1
    elif number == 0:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to continue prompting for numbers until a zero is entered.  An easy way to do this is to put your numbers into a list, which you can then compute the different stats from at the end:

```
numbers = []
while not numbers or numbers[-1] != 0:
    numbers.append(int(input("Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0: ")))
numbers.pop()  # discard the 0

print("The number of positives is", sum(n > 0 for n in numbers))
print("The number of negatives is", sum(n < 0 for n in numbers))
print("The total is", sum(numbers))
print("The average is", sum(numbers) / len(numbers))
```

Comment: @Abastien Please see [What to do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), this will help future readers and also allow to mark other questions as duplicates. Thank you!